# How to get xpos of a div's background image?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple script which is meant to console.log the xpos of a div's background image but the console shows blank.

This is what i have:

```
    var d = document.getElementById('div');
    console.log(d.style.backgroundPosition); //shows a blank line
    console.log(d.style.backgroundPosition.xpos); //undefined (obviously)
```

I'm curious why backgroundPosition is coming out blank though?

The div's CSS is:

```
 #div{
    background-image: url('test.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
 }
```

The html as requested:

```
<body>   
    <div id="div"></div>
</body>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: Ok done that got a huge amount of CSS, what should i look for in particular ? I've never used this function before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `console.log(d.style.backgroundPosition);` only works for styles set inline. To get the styles set via a style sheet, use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(d).getPropertyValue("background-position"); // returns 0px 0px
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yZ9Kc/)**

If you want just the X or Y position, use `"background-position-x"` or `"background-position-y"`.

Comment: Is there no way to extra xpos and ypos to separate variables?

Comment: If you want just the X or Y position, use "background-position-x" or "background-position-y".

Comment: Can i change the background position that way or do i have use the `d.style.backgroundPosition =` method?

Comment: No you can set it with something like `d.style.backgroundPosition='20px 20px';` or `d.style.backgroundPositionX='20px';`